# Using a variable to access a Map in JSP EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I would like to use a JSP variable to access the elements of a Map in JSP, but I can't make it work. Here is what I tried:

```
<p>1. ${backups["2011-06-09_web05"]}</p>
<p>2. <c:set var="key" value="2011-06-09_web05"/> ${backups[$key]}</p>
```

I thought the two to be equivalent, but the first expression prints the value contained in the index specified, while the second doesn't print anything.

What is the right syntax? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` prefix. It is invalid. You probably had PHP in mind.

```xml
<p>2. <c:set var="key" value="2011-06-09_web05"/> ${backups[key]}</p>
```

Comment: Yes, probably. However also EL has $ prefix, but as you made me notice is only around the overall expression. It works, thank you again!

Comment: The whole EL expression goes in `${...}`. Nesting EL expressions is invalid. See Java EE 6 tutorial for more examples http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html (also linked in our EL wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)